# Ruby gives conflicting match in regular expression after permutation of RE conditions

Tags: ruby, regex

In the following, lines 29 and 35 are exactly the same. Why are their return value different?

```
27: str = "ABC123"
    #=> "ABC123"
29: "It's a match" if ( str.to_s =~ /w+/ )
    #=> nil
30: "It's a match" if ( str.to_s =~ /[a-z]/ )
    #=> nil
31: "It's a match" if ( str.to_s =~ /[a-zA-Z]/ )
    #=> It's a match
32: "It's a match" if ( str.to_s =~ /[a-z]/ )
    #=> nil
33: "It's a match" if ( str.to_s =~ /[\w+\W+]/ )
    #=> It's a match
34: "It's a match" if ( str.to_s =~ /[\w+]/ )
    #=> It's a match
35: "It's a match" if ( str.to_s =~ /\w+/ )
    #=> It's a match
36: "It's a match" if ( str =~ /\w+/ )
    #=> It's a match
```

My initial answer is that one of my expressions that evaluated to `true` assigned the `true` to `str`. That just wouldn't make sense, though. My working environment is Ruby 1.9.1 with Rails 3.0.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line 29 you forgot to put `\` before `w+`.

```
puts "It's a match" if str =~ /\w+/
```

Gentle remarks: you don't need brackets in this case and you don't need `.to_s` as str is already a string.

```
puts "It's a match" if str =~ /[a-z]/i # i makes it case insensetive
```

Also in irb it is just easier to use either `str =~ /\w+/` or even `str[/\w+/]` to see the result.

Answer (score 3):

Actually Line 29 is looking for w while line 35 is looking for a word character. Line 29 has `/w+/` which means look for w while Line 35 has /\w+/ which means look for a word character, i.e. `[0-9A-Za-z_]`